# How show button to run current file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently, in one of my Visual Studio Code instances, now there is a green "play" button that allows me to **Run Python File in Terminal**.

You can see that button in the picture below, just between the "open changes" and the "split editor" buttons.

[image]

I have Visual Studio code installed in other computers, and there is no such button. I would like to show that button since it comes very handy, but I do not know how to make that happen, and I cannot find any documentation.

Note: I'm not using any extension for running files

Comment: Do you have the Python Marketplace Add in installed? Also does it show the Python version at the bottom of the IDE? (in white writing on blue background IIRC) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: I don't know about the Python Marketplace Add. And yes, I see the Python version. In all my installations I can run the python files using contextual menu ( right-clicking on the file in the browser window and selecting the run command), it is just the button that is not appearing in some installation.

Comment: Did you look at that link carefully? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger - launch.json etc.

Comment: Yes, I did, I can launch the debugger, run files and all, my question is about the little button appearing in the top bar of the editor. I do not know why I get it with one of my instances of VScode but not with other. I'm using the very same version, same python project, same launcher configuration...

Comment: Do you see launch.json in the one that shows it and none it the one that doesn't?

Comment: I have the same launch.json in both

Comment: Are the versions of Visual Studio identical?

Comment: Yes they are, same VS Code versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Play' button feature is in testing at the moment, and so is only available to those in the experiment group.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5321

Having said that, I had the button appear yesterday part way through a session.
Unfortunately, today the button is no longer present, and I am not part of the experiment group.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. In my case, the button suddenly appeared in my second VS Code instance two days ago :D

Answer (score 1):

Install Code Runner simple by press (Ctrl+shift+X) and search for "Code Runner",it works for almost all languages including python. it gives you a button and shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N.

Comment: the button I'm talking about is not installed by the Code Runner plugin, it is a native feature of VS Code

Answer (score 0):

This area is called "Editor Actions". It's now available by default but unfortunately cannot be hidden unless you modify stylesheet:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403